# MongoDB $geoNear distance is different than Google Maps distance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps

I have a list of Venues in my DB and I wish to show those in order of distance to the client.

My query to the DB is the following:

```
    venueCollection.aggregate([
        {
            '$geoNear': {
                'near': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [ user_lng , user_lat ]
                },
                'spherical': true, 
                'distanceField': 'dist'
            }
        },
        {
            '$sort': {
                'dist': 1
            }
        }
    ], function (err, venues) {
        // my code...
    });
```

A simple Document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56ec1c833e017f403870e2c5"),
    "name" : "A & H",
    "city" : "'s-Gravenhage",
    "province" : "Zuid Holland",
    "location" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [ 
            4.276930300000004, 
            52.0732475
        ]
    }
}
```

It show a list of Venues and the `distance` field is correct, from closest to farthest.

Client side I use the `latitude` and `longitude` (same I pass to the server and the same of the venue) to calculate distance with Google Maps:

```
      var venuePosition = new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.lat, attrs.lng);
      var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(scope.user.position.compiled, venuePosition);
      element.text((distance / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' km');
```

it show correctly the distance between 2 points.

The issue is that the 2 values (from Mongo and from gMaps) are different and even if the list is correctly displayed using `$sort` from mongoDB it show distances that are not in Order, ie.:

```
venue 01: 21.350km
venue 02: 21.412km
venue 03: 21.388km // wrong!!!
venue 04: 21.547km
```

Where is the error?
I need to sort my venues in distance order and show the distance in km... and it should be ordered too...

Comment: Please update your post along with verifiable code and MongoDB documents.

Comment: I added sample document but I don't think it is necessary. Just test every location with latitude and longitude and another position to get distance. Mongo return different distances than Google Maps...
You don't actually need my Documents...

Comment: MongoDB assume earth is a perfect sphere when calculating distance which is not. If your application is distance sensitive, do not depend on MongoDB for accuracy.

Comment: Ok, but why passing the same latitude and longitude to two different services I have completely different distances? And I still do not understand what `distanceField` exactly return... it is not meters, nor miles... just numbers...

Comment: See my post below. I tried to explain why you are getting two different results

Comment: `distanceField` returns value in meters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB assumes earth is perfect sphere and uses average radius of earth to calculate distance between two points. But as you know earth is not sphere but more sort of Ellipsoid so distance calculation will not be perfect  but approximate in MongoDB. However, Google uses very complex formula to get better results. They do have huge database of radius of earth at different locations on earth.

See this website which explains and have online calculator to compute distance between two points using average radius of earth.

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/

You will see that distance calculated by above website and MongoDB are same.

However, if you want to get near accurate result, see following link http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. It uses very complex algorithem to get better result.

Comment: Well, it doesn't solve my issue but now I know why it happen. Thanks

Comment: Well, this is whole point. Your problem will not be solved by MongoDB alone. You need to decide if your application can live with some inaccuracy or precision is deal breaking.

Comment: Yes it can. I just wish my data to be ordered properly. Even if I don't think the `distance` is in meters because the difference between mongo distance and gMaps distance is too much...

Comment: Well it's value depends on your index type. If your index is 2d, it will be in radians and if index type is 2dsphere, distance will be in meters.