# GeoData given different distances between two points in MySQL and MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, postgresql, gis

I'm doing some benchmark between some databases, but comparing distance query between MySQL/Postgres and MongoDB gives me different results.

For example, in MySQSL

```
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(
  POINT(-74.0060, 40.7128), -- New York
  POINT(-118.2437, 34.0522) -- Los Angeles
) AS distance;
```

gives me the result:

```sql
┌───────────────────┐
│     distance      │
├───────────────────┤
│ 3935737.605975668 │
└───────────────────┘
```

This result remains the same using equivalent functions in Postgres.

But in MongoDB (using NodeJS)

```js
// Inserting New York into database to be filtered afterwards

nodes_collection.insertOne({
  _id: 123456,
  location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [-74.006, 40.7128]},
});


let result = client.nodes_collection.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [-118.2437, 34.0522],  % Los Angeles
      },
      distanceField: 'distance',
      spherical: true,
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 123456,  // Filter only the point of interesting 
    },
  },
]);
```

gives me the result:

```sql
┌───────────────────┐
│     distance      │
├───────────────────┤
│ 3940132.347594769 │
└───────────────────┘
```

It shows an approximate 4,395 meters difference.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I cannot address Mongodb, but still a likely cause is the difference between spheroid  and spherical calculations. Spheroid calculations account for the *flattening* of the earth's surface due to axial rotation. Spherical calculations are simplified by assuming the earth to be a perfect sphere. (Postgres/Postgis support both). Make sure the systems are using the same assumptions.

Comment: Postgis has a different result. Maybe related to [which earth radius](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262457/where-does-the-default-earth-radius-in-st-distance-sphere-come-from) is used?

Comment: Belayer is correct, MongoDb uses spherical approximation according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646641/mongodb-geonear-distance-is-different-than-google-maps-distance

Comment: @JGH thanks for pointing this out, the numerical convention of my country uses dots as thousands separation, as I paste the result from my calculator I didn't realized it to do this change

Comment: @Belayer I didn't know about how complex these calculations could be. I'll try to find a standard between all databases

Comment: Rather than trying to find a standard decide which in best for your application.  There is always a trade off. the tradeoff here is accuracy vs. speed.  Spheroid calculations are slightly more accurate where as Spherical calculations are faster.  You may want to see [Spheroids and spheres](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/projections/spheroids-and-spheres.htm) and [Postgis.ST_Distance](https://postgis.net/docs/en/ST_Distance.html). Then ask yourself *is 4K distance error accross the US significant to my app.* I would think most databases provide both.

Comment: @Belayer precisely, my application must evaluate performance in diverse databases, that's why I have to find the commun results for each query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without altering default parameter values:

1. MySQL's [`ST_Distance_Sphere()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) assumes the Earth's radius is 6370986 meters: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/dXi5uU8V)
2. PostgreSQL's (PostGIS) [`ST_DistanceSphere()`](https://postgis.net/docs/en/ST_DistanceSphere.html) assumes a radius of 6371008 meters: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/phdhJ7LR)
3. MongoDB's [`$nearSphere`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/indexes/index-types/geospatial/2d/calculate-distances/#procedure) assumes 6378100 meters: [demo](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/3hyL5wM2sfi)

Different sphere radius means different distance between the same angular coordinate pairs. Two dots on a baloon get further away from each other the more you inflate it.

You mentioned when you feed the coords to each system, you specify them to be in [EPSG 4326](https://epsg.io/4326). That [CRS/SRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) is based on [WGS84 *ellipsoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84), not a sphere. The spec describes its semi-major axis, "longer, sideways radius" as `6378137.0 m` and smi-minor, "shorter, vertical" one as `6356752.314245 m`, with `298.257223563` inverse flattening.

When given that SRS/CRS, to get a radius for spherical distance measurement:

1. MySQL checks the ellipsoid parameters and takes an average of `(2a+b)/3`, where `a` is the semi-major axis and `b` is the semi-minor axis of the SRS. In this case that's `(2 * 6378137.0 + 6356752.314245) / 3 =` **`6371008.771415059`**
2. PostgreSQL seems to derive it the same way and arrives at **6371008.771415061** meters, around its default.
3. MongoDB uses that exact CRS by default, so it keeps its default of **6378100** meters. The documentation doesn't clarify how that's obtained.

It doesn't seem you can easily change the radius used for MongoDB's spherical distance in `$geoNear`/`$nearSphere` or define and use a custom CRS, so if your goal is as much of an apples-to-apples comparison as possible between these systems, you could instead stop using SRID 4326 when taking the measurement in MySQL and PostgreSQL and instead use the third positional parameter (the custom sphere radius) for their `ST_Distance_Sphere()` and `ST_DistanceSphere()`, setting it to `6378100` in order to conform to MongoDB's configuration.

You could also keep SRID 4326 in MySQL and PostgreSQL and set MongoDB to apply a [`distanceMultiplier: 6371008.771415061 / 6378100`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/#definition), in order to correct for the disproportion between the different radii.

All of this is demonstrated in the demo links up top.