# How to do Geospatial Queries in PostgreSQL like in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I have a Java Spring backend with a a PostgreSQL database.
I have some objects where they have a langitude and longitude.
I want to make a query to find all objects within a radius.

How can I achieve it?

I did this for a similar project with an express.js backend and a MongoDB database where I can use geospatial queries (using GeoJSON and 2dsphere.

For example like this

```
const getPoisByRadius = async (req, res) => {
   let coords = [];
   coords[0] = req.body.lng;
   coords[1] = req.body.lat;
   let maxDistance = 15000;
   let place_id_list = [];


   await PoiDB.Poi.find(
      {
         location: {
            $near: {
               $geometry: {
                  type: 'Point',
                  coordinates: coords,
               },
               $maxDistance: maxDistance,
            },
         },
      },
      '_id',
      async (err, result) => {
         if (err) return res.status(500).send({ errorMessage: err });
         const idResArray = result.map((elem) => {
            return String(elem._id);
         });
         const toursWithPoi = await TourDB.Tour.find({
            $or: [{ 'sights._id': { $in: idResArray } }, { 'sights.place_id': { $in: place_id_list } }],
         }).exec();
         return res.status(200).send(toursWithPoi);
      }
   );
};
```

I am not sure how I can achieve it in Java using a PostgreSQL DB.

I read that PostgreSQL use the `earthdistance` module and then somehow by calculating with the Haversine formula `@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM your_entity_table WHERE (6371 * acos(cos(radians(:latitude)) * cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(:longitude)) + sin(radians(:latitude)) * sin(radians(latitude)))) < :radius", nativeQuery = true)`

But I am not sure how exactly.

Comment: If you really want to have fun with geo{metric,graphic} data, use the [PostGIS](http://postgis.net)  extension; and its [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.4/ST_DWithin.html) function.

Comment: Use PostGIS. [Distances will be very slightly different from those produced by MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77034329/5298879) because PostGIS uses a more precise value for the radius of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

If you [`CREATE EXTENSION PostGIS;`](https://postgis.net/documentation/getting_started/), the lengthy code you showed:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM your_entity_table 
                WHERE (6371 
                       * acos(  cos(radians(:latitude)) 
                                * cos(radians(latitude)) 
                                * cos(  radians(longitude) 
                                      - radians(:longitude) ) 
                              + sin(radians(:latitude))
                                * sin(radians(latitude)) 
                             )
                      ) < :radius"
       , nativeQuery = true)
```

reduces to a more declarative [*within-distance* condition](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html):

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM your_entity_table 
                WHERE ST_DWithin( your_point
                                 ,ST_MakePoint(:longitude,:latitude)
                                 ,:radius)"
       , nativeQuery = true)
```

And now it can use an [R-Tree-over-GiST index](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on `your_point`, speeding things up significantly. Also your and MongoDB's `6371` km Earth radius is now a bit more precise `6371008` meters assumed in PostGIS by default.